# bash script zip filename parsing strangely

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, zip

I'm trying to zip various files together (one of the included files is actually a zip itself) and name the resulting zip based on a handful of bash variables defined earlier. One of the variables used in the zip file name is being parsed from a #define in a config.h file. I successfully parsed together a .zip with the correct name, but when I tried to implement the same zip script in a slightly different situation I get erroneous zip names.

In Windows explorer, the  erroneous zip name looks something like `X1276N~E.ZIP`
In linux the zip appears with the intended name except with a question mark (which I've come to understand to be some sort of placeholder). i.g. `foo-stuff-bar-9.1b?.zip`

My current code trying to zip a file with name `foo-stuff-bar-9.1b.zip`:

```
foo_name=$1
bar_name=$2
rev_number=$(grep define[[:space:]]*SOME_NUMBER $directory/config.h | awk '{print $3;}'| tr -d '/"')
archive_name="$foo_name"-stuff-"$bar_name"-9."$rev_number"
zip "$archive_name".zip file1 file2 backup1.zip file3
```

So "foo_name" and "bar_name" are strings coming from the terminal when the script is run, "rev_number" is being parsed from config.h, and I'm formatting it all into "archive_name" before using it in the zip command.

I've tried all sorts of variations of quotation marks and brackets and I get the same weird name name no matter what I try. I'm not sure where my error is being caused as I'm parsing from many sources. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: that's normal. `?` is a valid character in a linux filename, but is illegal in Windows. So Windows will translate the illegal name into something that's still usable, and do it using the LFN->SFN conversion engine. And of course, that `?` might not actually be a `?`. it could just be the shell displaying a `?` to cover up some other non-standard character.

Comment: I know it's valid, but I'm not sure why or where it's coming from.

Comment: probably from `rev_number`. start breaking down your individual bits of the rev_number definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Marc B's suggestion, I piped the string to `xxd -b` to look at each character byte by byte. It appeared as though I was accidentally parsing a  character at the end of $archive_name when scraping the config.h file.

I was able to fix this by just piping my string through `tr -d "[:cntrl:]"` to remove the any control characters that would give weird file names.